# Pegar um valor de um select no Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-2.0, django-queryset

O código HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Produtos</h1>
    {% block content %}
    <form action = "{% url 'produtos' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <legend class="lead">PRODUTOS </legend>
            <select name="m" class="form-control">
            {% for marcas in m %}
                <option value="{{marcas.codigo_id}}">{{ marcas }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            </select>

            <select name="anome" id="anome">
            {% for aparelhos in a %}
                <option value="aparelhos">{{ aparelhos }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            </select>

            <select name="pnome" id="pnome">
            {% for produtos in p %}
                <option value="produtos">{{ produtos }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <input type = 'submit' value="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
    {% endblock content %}
    </body>
</html>
```

O código Django (Views)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Marcas, Aparelhos, 
Produtos

def marcas(request):
    mnome = request.POST.get("mnome", None)
    anome = request.POST.get("anome", None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
        if mnome:
            m = Marcas.objects.all()
            if m == 'Apple':
                anome = a
                a = Aparelhos.objects.filter(marca_id=1)
            else:
                anome = a
                a = Aparelhos.objects.filter(marca_id=1)


    return render(request, 'produtos.html',{'a': a, 'm': m })
```

Então como faço para capturar um valor selecionado nos meus select(html) e usa-lo nas minhas views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do ponto de vista da boa modelagem de dados você deveria ter definido em `Models` uma associação entre `Aparelho` e `Fabricante` (já que um aparelho é produzido por um fabricante) mas o pouco que está descrito do código não é possível saber se ela realmente existe. Mas vou considerá-la no exemplo e considerar que `Models` está mais ou menos assim:

```
class Aparelho(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Aparelho(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    fabricante = models.ForeignKey(
        Fabricante, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="aparelho_fabricante"
    )
```

Sendo assim, em `Views` você precisa acrescentar a lista de fabricantes ao escopo de variáveis que manda para o *template*:

```
# ...
contexto = {
    # aqui o que você já passa para o contexto
    "fabricantes": Fabricante.objects.all()
    }
return render(request, "template.html", contexto)
```

Daí no *template* você pode fazer usar:

```
<select>
{% for fabr in fabricantes %}
    <option value="{{ fabr.id }}">{{ fabr.nome }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Daí, a função que receberá os dados em `Views` já terá o `id` correto que você precisa utilizar.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!